# Which YUV format should I select for computing PSNR of video sequence?

Tags: image-processing, video, video-processing, yuv

For example I can give one of following video formats:

400

411

420

422

444

Selecting every video format is showing different PSNR value for video sequence.
OR Is there any way I can determine YUV video data format of my input YUV video sequence?

Comment: Have you solved your problem or do you need more help?

Answer (score 1):

**Y-PSNR:** you can simply extract the `Y` component of the original and the reference images, and calculate the PSNR value for each image/video frame.

For video: you need to calculate the mean value of the all estimated PSNR values.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, PSNR is reported against each channel of color space.

> Alternately, for color images the image is converted to a different color space and PSNR is reported against each channel of that color space, e.g., YCbCr or HSL.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio

For computing PSNR of video, you must have the source video, and the same video after some kind of processing stage.

> PSNR is most commonly used to measure the quality of reconstruction of lossy compression codecs).

In case color sub-sampling (e.g converting YUV 444 to YUV 420), is part of the lossy compression pipeline, it's recommended to include the sub-sampling in the PSNR computation.
Note: There is no strict answer, it depends what you need get measured.

Example:
Assume input video is YUV 444, and H.264 codec were used from lossy compression, and assume pre-processing stage is converting YUV 444 to YUV 420.
Video Compression: `YUV444 --> YUV420 --> H264 Encoder`.

You need to reverse the process, and then compute PSNR.
Video Reconstruction: `H264 Decoder --> YUV420 --> YUV444`.

Now you have input video in YUV 444 format, and reconstructed video in YUV 444 format, apply PSNR computation of the two videos.

---

Determine YUV video data format of input YUV video:

I recommend using `ffprobe` tool.
You can download it from here: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html (select "Static Linking").
I found the solution here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips.

You can use the following example:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=pix_fmt -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

Comment: Hi Asad, can you please give me some feedback?